# ExpandableObjectConverter for fields

Tags: xna, field, propertygrid, typeconverter

I know that expandableobjectconverter works with properties but i'm writing a 2D level designer that works with XNA Vector2 structures

This structures has X, Y "fields", not properties, there is a way to expand it just like it were properties?? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may create a class that contains the Vector2 and has Properties for X and Y, aswell as the Vector2 element itself.

You could also write your own Vector2 that can generate an XNA-Vector2 for drawing.
This would be my first try.

Something like the following, but with overloaded operators to make it easier to work with:

```
public class SerializableVector2 
{
    Vector2 internal;

    public Vector2 Internal {
        get { return internal; }
        set { internal = value; }
    }

    public float X {
        get { return internal.X; }
        set { internal.Y = value; }
    }

    public float Y {
        get { return internal.Y; }
        set { internal.Y = value; }
    }
}
```